# How can I store a energy from a low output?

Tags: battery-charging, charging, energy

I need a simple answer to a simple question: How can I store energy as in a battery to use it as energy for an LED lamp or something else? The available power is 50mV- 60mV and 70mA - 80mA.

Comment: Your question is not very specific, you can store the energy in a capacitor trivially but that is probably not what you want.  try "wearable energy harvesting" as a search

Comment: 50mV and what current? What are your load requirements. If you want to know how to store it, use a capacitor.

Comment: Please measure the I-V curve of this 50mV source, then edit the question and add this information in. When you're done, flag this comment as "No longer needed".

Comment: What is meant by "store"? I assume that you wish to use it somehow. What is the source? How much energy? What is the intended use? || This device may help - https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/technical-articles/ltc3108energyharvest.pdf  | They say 20 mV in but 10 mV could probably be accommodated.

Comment: Datasheet here https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3107f.pdf

Comment: I edited my post and added some details

Comment: If you want to operate a white LED with about 4 V and 20 mA for one  minute you need 4.8 Wh. 50 mV and 70 mA for 1 hour is 12.6 Wh. I would expect an efficiency lower than about 20 %.

Comment: It is almost always unwise to think or say that your question is simple. It MAY be simple, but if you do not know what it takes it ,may be very complicated indeed. In this case a simple answer is "use an LTC 310-7 or 3108". Whether that meets your need is uncertain as you have given us far less information than you could.